# HTTP Download From Java Server

Tags: java, http, java-server

I need to write a small java server that can be accessed through a web browser to download a file, preferably using sockets. Could anyone point me in the right direction as I can only find examples for the reverse (downloading from http using a java client).

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to, embed Jetty to do this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: That's sorta the heavy weight way to do it but I know from experience it works really well. :-)

Comment: Does this come in the standard java? It's for a computing course so unfortunately I can't use things that make it easier. I have used sockets throughout the rest of it, and I think that's what they want us to do.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your over all requirements (ie protocol restrictions), you could start be looking at

- [All about sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)
- As has already been mentioned, you could look into using [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)
- [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)
- Just about any other HTTP server??

Much of what it will come down to is:

- How much complexity you want to get into (time and energy)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 3rd party libraries for this such as [JBoss Netty](https://netty.io/) and [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) or [Apache HTTP Comp](http://hc.apache.org/) .  Also, I don't know much about it, but the new JDK7 has some [new NIO apis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) which might possibly do the job also.

Here is [a sample HTTP Server](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java) written with Apache HC.

NOTE: I think the trendy way of doing this sort of thing is to use "Web Sockets" which you will find info about that in the links I provided.